# Testing variable by given rules

Tags: java, exception, variables, methods

Need to write a quick method `static boolean varTest(String id)` that tests of the input is indeed a variable based on the following rules:

variable ::= a dollar sign ($) followed by an integer, or
             any identifier starting with a letter followed by a mix of letters or digits.

Where for example both x$ or $x can be var's without this test.

So if not true, I want to throw ArithmeticException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a regular expression: `$(\$[0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)^`.

For example:

```
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("$(\\$[0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)^");
static boolean varTest(String id) {
    return p.matcher(id).matches();
}
```

Comment: .matches returns true/false I assume?

Comment: @John: Yes; it returns a `boolean`.